# Python Dictionary (Edit only values of Dictionary)

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am beginner with python. I have a list. I want to loop over values of list and add each to my dictionary values respectively. It looked simple but I tried to write few loops but none was working for me. For example

```
   Note :  Total number of element in My_list and total number of key:value pairs in My_Dict are same.

   My_list= [ [A,B,C], [D,E,F], [I,J,K] ]

   My_dict= { 'Apple'= {'Color'=[data1,data2]} , 'Orange'= {'Color'=[data3,data4]}, 'Peach'={ 'color'=[data5,data6]} }
```

I was trying to get following format by adding each element of My_list to respective value of dictionary.

```
  New_Dict=  { 'Apple'= { 'Name'=[A,B,C], 'Color'=[data1,data2]} , 'Orange'= { 'Name'=[D,E,F] ,'Color'=[data3,data4]}, 'Peach'={ 'Name'=[I,J,K], 'color'=[data5,data6]} }
```

Comment: How do you know which list, e.g. `[A,B,C]` goes with which key in `NewDict`?

Comment: From the example and your comment about the number of elements of the dict and the list to match, it looks like you're expecting the `My_dict` object to maintain the order of its keys. Python dicts do not do that - they return their key/value pairs in arbitrary order. Since you're on 2.7, you can use `collections.OrderedDict` to maintain order.

Comment: @Cyber: Its like first element in My_list goes with first key:value pair in My_Dict as shown.

Comment: @sam1 You should not depend on the "first pair in My_Dict", dictionaries are unordered and you should not depend on them to have an order.

Comment: @Cyber: Oh yea, that made sense. In future dictionary might change a little. and it will change the order and my list will not sync to data in dict then. Hmm okay thanks for help. I will try something else then dictionary. or is there any way we can just fixed order of dictionary. I think as Peter DeGlopper said i can use collections.OrderedDict to maintain order right ?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, you need to use a [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead of regular `dict` in order to preserve the ordering of `my_dict`. From there, you can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over the keys in `my_dict` and the elements of `my_list` in lockstep, and insert each item in `my_list` to the appropriate place in the `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

my_list = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F'], ['I', 'J', 'K']]
my_dict = OrderedDict([ 
    ('Apple', {'Color' : ['data1','data2']}), 
    ('Orange', {'Color' : ['data3','data4']}), 
    ('Peach', { 'color' : ['data5','data6']}), 
])

for key, name in zip(my_dict, my_list):
    my_dict[key]['Name'] = name

print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('Apple', {'Color': ['data1', 'data2'], 'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C']}), ('Orange', {'Color': ['data3', 'data4'], 'Name': ['D', 'E', 'F']}), ('Peach', {'color': ['data5', 'data6'], 'Name': ['I', 'J', 'K']})])
```